# Como utilizar Python para pesquisar e armazenar dados da API do Stack Overflow?

Tags: python, stackexchange

Eu preciso desenvolver um trabalho para armazenar dados sobre o Stack Overflow. Quero saber como acessar a API da Stack Exchange com Python, e como usar a API.

Answer (score 5):

A API da Stack Exchange é toda RESTful, ou seja, você só precisa fazer requisições HTTP para determinada URL, e recebe uma resposta em JSON. Não existe nenhum cliente oficial para Python, mas [o Renan achou um no GutHub](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17324/74). Pelo que pesquisei (não sou usuário de Python), se quiser fazer na unha, bastaria usar a [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) (`http.client` em Python 3) para fazer as requisições.

A documentação sobre todos os métodos disponíveis na API você encontra em http://api.stackexchange.com/docs.

Answer (score 4):

Vou lhe dar um dado sobre o Stack Overflow: tanto aqui quanto na matriz em inglês as pessoas em geral não gostam de perguntas pedindo por tutoriais. Existe inclusive um motivo padrão para fechamento de questões, quando se tratam disso.

Isso é só uma dica. Uma vez que você irá realmente fazer um trabalho sobre o assunto, vou lhe indicar duas fontes:

- A API oficial: http://api.stackexchange.com/. Note que a API é para Javascript;
- Py-StackExchange: https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange. É uma API ***NÃO OFICIAL*** para python. Ela na verdade integra a oficial com Python.

Se tiver dúvidas, ambas possuem alguma documentação. Quando tiver algum problema mais específico, não hesite em abrir uma questão. Mas que seja um problema bem específico mesmo, ok? Faça sempre um pouco de *rubber ducking* antes.

Comment: Então, meu jovem amigo. Creio que você esteja equivocado na interpretação a respeito do meu problema. Sim é um problema específico de programação, preciso saber como acessar a api utilizando python, só não é comum como a maioria que colam pedaços de códigos com erros e pedem ajuda com correção. A palavra "Tutorial" foi usada, porque eu realmente não tenho uma base sobre o problema e precisaria de uma resposta mais completa. De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Além das respostas do [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17323/1333) e do [Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17324/1333), dando uma rápida pesquisada no [StackApps](http://stackapps.com), encontrei [essa pergunta](https://stackapps.com/questions/1722/pyso-py-python-stack-overflow-library), que linka para o projeto da [pyso](https://github.com/jwatney/pyso), que funciona corretamente para Python 2.6 e já fornece vários métodos para aquisição de dados.

Com uma análise rápida dessa lib, é possível verificar que ela foi desenvolvida utilizando [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) e [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) para fazer as requisições HTTP.